# Why NEXTjs does not update automatically when react query request is changed

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I make a simple get request using @tanstak/react-query in Nextjs. But my problem is that if I change the endpoint, nextjs is performing fast reload and it's compiling the data once again, but I see in the network tab, that it still sending the request to the previous endpoint. In order to get my changes I have to stop the server and run it once again. This is happening in dev mode.
My package.json looks like this:

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.11",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.11",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.35.7",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.35.7",
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "next": "^13.3.4",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "supports-color": "^9.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tanstack/eslint-plugin-query": "^4.36.0",
    "@types/node": "20.8.0",
    "@types/react": "18.2.23",
    "eslint": "latest",
    "eslint-config-next": "latest",
    "typescript": "5.2.2"
  }
}
```

And the component where I am sending the request:

```
'use client';

import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import axios from 'axios';

import React from 'react';

const Fixtures = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, isError } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['todos'],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos'
      );
      return data;
    },
  });
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</div>;
};

export default Fixtures;
```

As you can see on the screenshot my request should be send to photos, but even after reload refresh etc still its the previous endpoint.

[image]